# Problem in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a query. It works if I comment out the part checking for the exclusion.

```
WHERE H.BatchId = 3  AND H.IsExcluded != 1
```

IsExcluded is a bit field that accepts NULL values.

All the values I'm selecting from are NULL, so that SHOULD be right. What am I doing wrong? It's returning no values the way it is, but if I comment out just the 'AND' and after, it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
WHERE H.BatchId = 3  AND (H.IsExcluded != 1 OR H.IsExcluded IS NULL)
```

Comment: wow I was doing H.IsExcluded = NULL. THANK YOU! Accepted once it lets me.

Comment: +1 - @Scott - NULL has no value (SQL thinks it could have ANY value or no value), so it won't respond normally to operators.

Comment: Good to know. I'm still learning. Been working professional (after college) for a few months now. Picking up stuff as I go along.

Comment: @Scott: Now (after college) is when you will *really* learn stuff. ;)

Comment: I seem to agree with that so far, haha.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL NULL != NULL as @scott said but you may use SET ANSI_NULLS OFF.

```
Declare @a INT = NULL
Declare @b INT = NULL
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
IF(@b = @a)
    PRINT 'NULL is equal to NULL'
ELSE
    PRINT 'NULL is not equal to  NULL'

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
IF(@b = @a)
    PRINT 'NULL is equal to NULL'
ELSE
    PRINT 'NULL is not equal to  NULL'
```

Output is:

- NULL is equal to NULL: ANSI_NULLS set to OFF
- NULL is not equal to NULL: ANSI_NULLS set to ON, this is the default SQL Server behaviour.